# gnome-tweak tool doesn't work

Tags: 12.04, gnome, system-settings

I decided to give the GNOME desktop a shot, so, i installed gnome-shell, and later i wanted to tweak things around a bit, to suit my preferences, for which i downloaded the gnome-tweak tool. Now, the gnome-tweak tool is supposed to show up in the menu as `Advanced Setting`, which it does, however, upon clicking it, i have the icon of Advanced Settings on the top left corner of my window, and along with that, an icon to indicate that it is loading. That's where it ends, the icon just disappears from the top menu, and the Advanced Settings app never opens.

How can this issue be solved?

**EDIT #1**

upon running the `gnome-weak-tool` command from the terminal i get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/gnome-tweak-tool", line 22, in <module>
    import gi
ImportError: No module named gi
```

Comment: run `gnome-tweak-tool` in the terminal as see if you get an error from there

Comment: @Cubiq, hi, i'm sorry for not replying sooner. i've updated the question with the error statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to purge and reinstall the gnome-tweak-tool

```
sudo apt-get purge gnome-tweak-tool && sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Also try to reinstall the package `python-gi`

```
sudo apt-get purge python-gi && sudo apt-get install python-gi
```

If that doesn't help try to apply the tweak found [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1909933).

Basically open the `/usr/bin/gnome-tweak-tool` file and replace `#!/usr/bin/env python` with `#!/usr/bin/python`